# Как можно проверить decimal на +-inf nan

Tags: c

Как можно проверить заданную структуру на +inf, -inf, nan

Я предполагаю, что будет 3 функции isPlusInf, isMinusInf, isNan, которые возвращают статус (int). Но как написать эти функции как это проверить?

gcc version 10.3.0
-Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c11
Libs v2.33

```
// bits [0] - содержит младшие разряды
// bits [1] - содержит средние разряды
// bits [2] - содержит большие разряды
// bits [3] - знак (index 31) и степень (index 16-23)
typedef struct {
  unsigned int bits[4];
} decimal;
```

Comment: а как используется эта структура. но если что, для int (по крайней мере в с++ на x86) нет такого понятия как inf и nan, любая последовательность бит имеет четкое определенное целое значение.

Comment: @KoVadim Ну например,
decimal num1 = {{0, 0, 0, 0}}; // 0
decimal num2 = {{1, 0, 0, 0}}; // 1
decimal num3 = {{1, 0, 0, 0}};
getSign(&num3); // num3 = -1

decimal *decimal = NULL; // это разве не будет nan/null?

Comment: нет, не будет. Это  будет указатель на объект класса, которому присвоено специальное значение `NULL`. Рекомендуется использовать `nullptr` c++11. А NaN - это результат недопустимой операции. Например деление на ноль. Причем, сам ноль - это не NaN, а вот результат попытки делить на ноль - уже NaN  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Comment: @Vovan2005 что это за тип и почему Вы решили, что для него может быть inf/nan?

Comment: @KoVadim ну судя по структуре - в последнем байте степень числа - пытались сделать собственный `float`

Comment: это какое же число там хотят сохранит тогда, если на порядок отведено 31 бит???

Comment: Там вообще всё странно. Порядок разрядов странный - сначала идут младшие? Ошибка в описании - третий байт отведен под старшие разряды, а дальше пишет что степень числа в битах 16-23 - т.е. как раз в третьем байте. А если в 3 байте степень, то в 4 байте используется только 1 бит под знак. Ну в общем сказка! :)

Comment: а, уже вижу, 16-23 - это 8 бит. тогда со степенью более-менее. Но тогда получается 3*32 бита как минимум под мантису. что же это такое? или тут просто ошибка и на самом деле хотелось использовать unsigned char

Comment: Думаю да, это ещё одна ошибка. Судя по нумерации бит в комментариях тип должен быть либо `unsigned char`, либо `uint8_t`

Answer (score 0):

Проверка восьмого бита на установлен:

```
int  isMinusInf(void) { return bits[3] & (1<<7); } // логическое и с числом 0b10000000
```

Состояние NaN относится не к числу, а к результату операции.
В принципе можно сделать `static` переменную-флаг (одну для всех объектов). Но логику работы с ней уже писать вам. Наверное, оптимально будет сделать и флаг и вашу структуру в одном пространстве имен. Что-то типа:

```
namespace MyFloat
{
   static bool isNan = false;
   typedef struct 
   {
      unsigned char bits[4];
   } decimal;
}
```

Но можно и в структуре:

```
typedef struct 
{
  static bool isNan = false;
  unsigned char bits[4];
} decimal;
```

Либо тогда резервировать ещё один бит для хранения флага NaN

```
// bits [3] - знак (index 31), флаг NaN (index 30) и степень (index 16-29)
```